# Maximum total force leads to closed linear universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Consider a closed FRW universe with proper radius of curvature $R$ filled with a fluid with mass density $\rho$ and pressure $P$.

Let us assume that the total force acting on the spherical boundary around us at radius $R$ is given by the fundamental maximum force in general relativity:

$$4\pi R^2\ P = -\frac{c^4}{G}.\tag{1}$$

As $P \sim \rho \sim 1/R^2$ then the [cosmological equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)) is

$$P=-\frac{1}{3}\rho c^2.\tag{2}$$

Consider the [first Friedmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Equations) without the cosmological constant:

$$\left(\frac{\dot R}{R}\right)^2+\frac{c^2}{R^2}=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho.\tag{3}$$

Substituting Eqn.$(1)$ and Eqn.$(2)$ into Eqn.$(3)$ we find that:

$R=c\ t.\tag{4}$

This seems quite an elegant solution that might describe our universe.

Perhaps Eqn.$(1)$ acts as a limit on the enormous negative pressure that the quantum vacuum is estimated to produce?

Does this argument have any merit?

**Zero energy universe?**

If we combine Eqn.$(1)$ and Eqn.$(2)$ and multiply through by $R$ then we obtain

$$\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\rho=\frac{c^2}{G}R.\tag{5}$$

The term $4\pi R^3/3$ is the volume of the $3$-ball enclosed by the spherical boundary at radius $R$. The spherical boundary itself is in spatially-curved FRW space but the $3$-ball is in a fictional 4D flat space in which FRW space can be embedded.

Let us define

$$M=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 \rho.\tag{6}$$

We assume that all the mass $M$ lies on the spherical boundary at radius $R$.

Combining Eqn.$(5)$ and Eqn.$(6)$ we find

$$\frac{GM}{R}=c^2.\tag{7}$$

Consider the total energy $E$ of any mass $m$ at rest comprising its rest mass energy and its Newtonian gravitational potential energy with the rest of the universe described by a shell of mass $M$ around it:

$$E = mc^2 - \frac{GMm}{R}.\tag{8}$$

When we substitute Eqn.$(7)$ into Eqn.$(8)$ we find

$$E=0.\tag{9}$$

This result is in accordance with the widely held belief that any closed universe has zero total energy.

Comment: Having left academia a decade ago I've basically lost all touch with research, but is Fulvio's $R=ct$ universe still a thing? I thought it was ridiculed to death even back then?

Comment: I think he’s still pursuing the idea.